# apache server stop working regularly

Tags: php, mysql, apache, stored-procedures

we have huge product in php our database(Mysql) is now approx 1GB and we have approx 750 tables.almost 900 stored routines are there. we are facing the problem that our apache server stop working after interval of some time.

Server configuration is

intel xeon processor
16 GB ram (DDR3)
1 tb hdd
**OS is Ubuntu 14.04**

Comment: I think you should post your error log so people can figure out what's wrong with your web server

Comment: [Sun Jun 25 08:00:38.668674 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1323] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.19 configured -- resuming normal 
[Sun Jun 25 11:23:15.934808 2017] [core:error] [pid 52345] [client 198.53.180.68:53397] AH00126: Invalid URI in request GET login.cgi HTTP/1.0
[Sun Jun 25 15:16:03.233309 2017] [core:error] [pid 52345] [client 167.62.49.109:37722] AH00126: Invalid URI in request GET login.cgi HTTP/1.0
[Mon Jun 26 01:09:47.135891 2017] [:error] [pid 38426] [client 91.196.50.33:58870] script '/var/www/doctorg/app/testproxy.php' not found or unable to stat